# change xml namespace

Tags: namespaces

I have an xml file as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ABC version="1" xmlns="urn:Company">
</ABC>
```

I am releasing version 2 and the namespace changed to "NewCompany".
How do you update the namespace?

I tried

> XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
>               using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create("myfile.xml"))
>               {
>                   xmlDocument.Load(xmlReader);
>               }

```
        XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("ABC");
        if (nodeList.Count == 1)
        {
            XmlElement element = nodeList.Item(0) as XmlElement;
            if (element != null)
            {
                element.SetAttribute("xmlns", "NewCompany");

                XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
                settings.Indent = true;
                using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("myfile.xml", settings))
                {
                    xmlDocument.WriteTo(writer);
                }
            }
        }
```

But I get 
"The prefix '' cannot be redefined from  to  within the same start element tag." 
exception

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this today and found a workaround. If you use XmlTextWriter instead of XmlWriter, the problem goes away. Your code sample would look something like this:

```
    XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("ABC");
    if (nodeList.Count == 1)
    {
        XmlElement element = nodeList.Item(0) as XmlElement;
        if (element != null)
        {
            element.SetAttribute("xmlns", "NewCompany");

            using (XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("myfile.xml", Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                xmlDocument.WriteTo(writer);
            }
        }
    }
```

I'd have imagined that XmlWriter.Create will simply return a XmlTextWriter, but that doesn't seem to be the case. From looking around in Reflector,  XmlWriter.Create seems to return concrete types *different* from XmlTextWriter.

XmlTextWriter seems to support changing the namespace of the document element, while the writer returned by XmlWriter.Create doesn't.

I realize that this question is four years old, but perhaps my answer will help someone.